# Classic ASP: Under what circumstances would Response object not be defined?

Tags: asp-classic, response

We have an ASP page:

**GetProducts.asp**

```
Response.Charset = "ISO-8859-1"
```

and after seven years we suddenly got the error:

```
Object not defined: Response
```

We changed the file to:

```
Alert("before");
Response.Charset = "ISO-8859-1"
Alert("after");
```

and then changed it back to:

```
Response.Charset = "ISO-8859-1"
```

And now all is well.

- Under what circumstances would the classic ASP `Response` object variable not be defined?
- Why would touching the file (that hasn't been touched in years) make the `Response` object defined again?

Answer (score 1):

response is an ASP thing, and alert is a javascript thing. You sure you didn't accidentally remove a closing `%>` somewhere that made javascript try to run an ASP instruction or viseversa?

Comment: Yes, i actually mistakenly put `Alert(...)` in the asp. i actually saw the alerts and the `Response` object was no longer undefined. Then i removed the two test lines, the alerts went away, and the `Response` remained valid.